# DataGrid formatter callback doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I'm using the following layout for my Dojo 1.5 DataGrid:

```
function getGridLayout() {
  return [{
    name: "Stylist",
    field: "stylist",
    width: "100px"
  },
  {
    name: "Service",
    field: "service",
    width: "200px"
  },
  {
    name: "Length",
    field: "length",
    width: "50px"
  },
  {
    name: " ",
    field: "remove",
    width: "30px",
    formatter: getRemoveFormatter
  }];
}
```

And here's my callback definition:

```
function getRemoveFormatter(item) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

And here's how I'm creating my DataGrid:

```
dojo.ready(function() {
  var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:{items:[]}});
  window.grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({store: store, structure: getGridLayout()}, document.createElement("div"));
  dojo.byId("services_grid").appendChild(grid.domNode);
  grid.startup();
  observeAppointmentServiceAddClick(window.grid);
  getAppointmentItems();
});
```

For some reason `item` is always `undefined`. Any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that, whenever I would add a row, I wouldn't define anything for the "remove" column, so naturally the item in that cell would be undefined.